# How to run Angular 7 unit tests with custom environment.test.ts settings?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, command-line-interface, test-environments

How do I get the Angular CLI to serve up the right environments/environment*.ts file in Angular 7?

I've tried configuring the replacement of the `environment.ts` with `environment.test.ts` in three different places with no success.

I've tried running it with `ng test` and with `ng test --configuration test`.

Every single time, if I debug the tests, I find that it's using `environment.prod.ts`(?!) instead of `environment.test.ts`.

Here is a screenshot to show the three places I've tried to do the `fileReplacements`:
[image]
Here is the entire config for reference:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "mms": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "mms",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/mms",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "src/assets/libs/pikaday/pikaday.scss",
              "src/assets/scss/dragula/dragula.css",
              "src/assets/libs/hopscotch/css/hopscotch.css",
              "src/assets/scss/site.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/libs/hopscotch/js/hopscotch.js",
              "src/assets/libs/pikaday/pikaday.js",
              "src/assets/libs/bitmovin-loader.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "test": {
              "fileReplacements": [{
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
              }]
            },
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                },
                {
                  "replace": "src/index.html",
                  "with": "src/index.prod.html"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            },
            "mastermock": {
              "main": "src/main-mock.ts",
              "fileReplacements": [{
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.mock.ts"
              }]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "mms:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "mms:build:production"
            },
            "mastermock": {
              "browserTarget": "mms:build:mastermock",
              "proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
            }
          }
        },
        "serve-local": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "mms:build",
            "proxyConfig": "proxy.local.conf.json"
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "mms:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config"
            ],
            "codeCoverageExclude": [
              "**/*.mock.ts",
              "**/*.module.ts"
            ],
            "fileReplacements": [{
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
            }]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "test": {
              "fileReplacements": [{
                "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
              }]
            },
            "production": {
              "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.prod.js"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**",
              "**/*.dev.ts",
              "**/e2e/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "mms-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.dev.js",
            "devServerTarget": "mms:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "local": {
              "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.dev.js",
              "devServerTarget": "mms:serve-local"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "mms",
  "schematics": {
    "@ngrx/schematics:component": {
      "styleext": "scss"
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "defaultCollection": "@ngrx/schematics"
  }
}
```

Comment: Try simply importing the desired environment file in your unit tests like this "import { environment } from './../environments/environment.test';".

Comment: @robert that led me to look deeper.  Looks like VSCode "helped" me by importing the .prod file into my component classes!  Removing the .prod should fix my issue.

Answer (score 13):

1. This was caused by Visual Studio Code "helping" me by importing:
   `import { environment } from '@environments/environment.prod';`
2. The right place for `fileReplacements` is in `architect.test.options.fileReplacements`.
3. In order to prevent VSCode from ever "helping" me like this again, I'm going to rename all of the `environment.*.ts` files other than `environment.ts` to something like `DO-NOT-IMPORT.ENVIRONMENT.*.ts`.  At least that'll yell at me if I get the wrong import.

Comment: This is exactly right. My test was importing the right environment file, but my production file under test was not. Thanks for being specific about where the option goes.

Comment: Do not name config files like this.
You can just add to tsconfig.ts path like 

"@environment": [ "./path/to/environment.ts" ]

Comment: @KusokBanana see point #1.  If you don't pay very careful attention then VSCode does the wrong thing too easily. This form of naming makes mistakes more obvious. It's not a rule, just a recommendation that could save you some time!

Comment: @KusokBanana I do see what you're saying, and how it would work as long as VSCode never decides to import from anything except the `@environment` path. It's not a bad way of solving this either.

Comment: @jkyoutsey If you do as I said then VSCode will never decide to import from environment.prod.ts because this would cause an error while compiling (or while using TSLint). The problem is not worth changing names of files

Comment: Didn't know that `architect.test.options` has `fileReplacements` option. Thanks

Comment: @jkyoutsey This doesn't seem to work for me in an Nx jest environment

Comment: @Jonathan002 I don't use NX or Jest so I can't help you out on that one. I'm sure the smart NX folks probably already have a good solution for this!

Answer (score 1):

When you add a custom environment configuration, you need to add it also to the `test` element in the `angular.json` file, otherwise tests just run with the default environment configuration.

For instance, lets say you added an extra environment configuration named "customenv" to the already existing `build.configurations` element:

```
"build": {
    ...

    "configurations": {
        "production": {
            "budgets": [
                {
                    "type": "initial",
                    "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                    "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                    "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                    "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
            ],
            "fileReplacements": [
                {
                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
            ],
            "outputHashing": "all"
        },
        "development": {
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "optimization": false,
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "namedChunks": true
        },
        "customenv": {
            "fileReplacements": [
                {
                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                    "with": "src/environments/environment.customenv.ts"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "defaultConfiguration": "production"
},
```

At this point you can run

```
ng build --configuration=customenv
```

And then you might have also modified the already existing `serve.configurations` element like this:

```
"serve": {
    ...
    "configurations": {
        "production": {
            "browserTarget": "myproject:build:production"
        },
        "development": {
            "browserTarget": "myproject:build:development"
        },
        "testws": {
            "browserTarget": "myproject:build:customenv"
        }
    },
    "defaultConfiguration": "development"
},
```

So now you can run:

```
ng serve --configuration=customenv
```

But if you try to run

```
ng test --configuration=customenv
```

You get the error:

> An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'customenv' is not set in the workspace.

To be able to do that, you need to create a `test.configurations` element and add only the new custom environment:

```
"test": {
    ...                  
    "configurations": {                        
        "customenv": {
            "fileReplacements": [
                {
                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                    "with": "src/environments/environment.customenv.ts"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add fileReplacements to the test section of angular.json

```
"test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
        "fileReplacements": [{
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
        }],
```

Tested angular-12.